# In php is there any way to load partial url

Tags: php

In php is there any way to load partial `url`

For example : `www.xyz.com/courses/six-sigma-green-belt-training-bangalore` is the current url, i want to load the page till this url `www.xyz.com/courses/six-sigma-green-belt-training`

Please help.

Comment: actually what you want to do?

Comment: `$url=str_replace('-bangalore','',$url);`

Comment: What do you exactly mean by partial? Like having only to remove the 6th word after `-`?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this simple url navigation class

```
class coursesNav {
    private $baseurl = 'www.xyz.com/courses/';
    private $pieces = array();
    public function __construct($url) {
        $this->pieces = explode('-', substr($url, strlen($this->baseurl)));
    }

    public function getLevel($pos) {
        return $this->baseurl.implode('-', array_slice($this->pieces, 0, $pos));
    }
}

$nav = new coursesNav('www.xyz.com/courses/six-sigma-green-belt-training-bangalore');
echo $nav->getLevel(5);
```

Comment: yes... you have to remove the "/ppa79dt31028"

Comment: i think that is the id for that particular page, if i remove that id goes to a 404 page,i want to remove only the -bangalore from url

Comment: as @Hanky mentioned use `$url=str_replace('-bangalore','',$url);`